# Key of null variable equals null not error

Tags: php

We've got variable that for some reason we think would be an array, but it happens to be null.

`$var = null`

We try to get a value from this variable.

`$value = $var['key']`

This doesn't throw an error, my intuition is that it would though. What instead happens is that $value is now also null. Is there a particular reason that the above line doesn't throw an error?

Comment: If I'm correct, trying to read a non-existing value of an array *does* throw an error. Do you have `error_reporting()` set to `-1`?

Comment: It doesn't throw an error, it would normally raise a notice, but that doesn't appear to be the case with `null`.

Comment: php never ceases to surprise me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is "almost duplicate": [Why does accessing array index on boolean value does not raise any kind of error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734975/why-does-accessing-array-index-on-boolean-value-does-not-raise-any-kind-of-error)

the code there looks like:

```
$var = false;
$value = $var['key'];
```

and the answer is - it's [just document](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

> Accessing variables of other types (not including arrays or objects implementing the appropriate interfaces) using [] or {} silently returns NULL.

So in this string (I am talking about your case, $var = null, but with boolean would be the same explanation, just replace NULL to boolean)

```
$var['key']
```

$var is the variable of [type NULL](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php), and accessing variable of type NULL (other type that array or object) using [] silently returns NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of fallback

```
function _get($from, $key)
{
    if(is_null($from))
    {
        trigger_error('Trying to get value of null');
        return null;
    }
    return $from[$key];
}
```

Change

```
$value = $var['key'];
```

to

```
$value = _get($var, 'key');
```